# A conditional probability problem on drawing balls from a bag?

Tags: probability

A ball is drawn at random from box I and transferred to box II. If the probability of drawing a red ball from box I, after this transfer, is \frac{1}{3} find $n_1$ and $n_2$, if $n_1$ is the number of reds in bag1 and $n_2$ is the number of blacks

my attempt:-p(red|balck transfered)= $\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2-1}$
and P(red|red transfered)=$\frac{n_1-1}{n_1+n_2-1}$
thus we have
$$\frac{n_1-1}{n_1+n_2-1}+\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2-1}= \frac{1}{3}$$

However, according to [this source](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-ball-is-drawn-at-random-from-box-i-and/),we calculate the intersection of removing a ball of a certain colour, and I'm not sure I understand why, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is simpler than it appears. If you don't look at the ball you transfered, then knowing that you transfered it doesn't give you any information. The second ball you pick is still equally likely to be any of the balls that were originally in box I. So your probability of getting red is just $$\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2},$$ the same as it would have been if you hadn't moved the first ball. You don't really need to use conditional probability at all.

But if you do use conditional probability, you can't just add the two conditional probabilities, you need to weight them by the probability that the condition holds:
$$P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|\overline B)P(\overline B)$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!